# npm error de loader: module build failed. options should be an option

Tags: npm

Al ejecutar mi comando `npm run start` me sale lo siguiente:

```
ERROR in ./assets/css/main.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Style Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options should be an object:
   object { injectType?, attributes?, insert?, base?, esModule? }
    at validate (/mnt/c/Users/Usuario/Documents/Coursers/Codigo_Facilito/Practica-Web_avanzado/Project/Stories-two/node_modules/style-loader/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (/mnt/c/Users/Usuario/Documents/Coursers/Codigo_Facilito/Practica-Web_avanzado/Project/Stories-two/node_modules/style-loader/dist/index.js:23:28)
 @ ./assets/javascript/entry.js 1:0-26
```

Estoy trabajando con webpack y unos loaders, entre ellos style-loader.

Answer (score 0):

La solución a esto es `npm install [modulo]`. Eso es todo